How to handle multiple navigation events on MAUI Android?
I'm experiencing an issue with MAUI's WebView (using custom WebViewClient) where rapid tapping on links causes unexpected behavior (or expected on Android not sure). The iOS version handles the multiple taps on random links quite well, it navigates to the last pressed link or the one that is currently loading. On Android though if the user taps on a link then while the page is loading (I know this is not normal user behaviour but I would like to handle it) the navigation stops working properly.
Specifically:

OnPageStarted() is called once (as expected)
While the page is still loading, if user taps other links multiple times:

OnPageFinished() gets called multiple times
ShouldOverrideUrlLoading() gets called the same amount of times as OnPageFinished()


This causes navigation issues and potential state management problems and sometimes the app will not navigate until whatever process is running in the background handling navigation finishes (not exactly sure how the lifecycle works)

What I want (if possible):

Block all navigation attempts while a page is actively loading if possible
Only allow the first navigation cycle to complete (OnPageStarted -> OnPageFinished)
Prevent OnPageFinished and ShouldOverrideUrlLoading from being called until the actual page has finished loading

Current implementation in my CustomWebViewClient is the default one for a hybridWebView, I have the three following overrides:
public override void OnPageStarted(WebView? view, string? url, Bitmap? favicon)
{
    // Standard navigation start logic
}

public override void OnPageFinished(WebView? view, string? url)
{
    // Getting called multiple times during page load
}

public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView? view, IWebResourceRequest? request)
{
    // Getting spammed with calls during page load
}


You can use a local variable to flag whether the codes of launching the page should be executed upon the 2nd clicking.
